# Unable to connect to gmail store javax mail api

Tags: java, api, jakarta-mail, ui-automation

I am trying since few days to retrieve email being sent using javax mail api. Dependency used -
`<artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>`

I am getting error messages like cannot connect to store or connection time out when it tries to connect to store. Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String userName = "mncjhc@gmail.com";
    String password = "ckjbc";
    String subjectKeyword = "New  Registration – Successful";
    String fromEmail = "djhgdd@gmail.com";
    String bodySearchText = "You have successfully register to our services";
    searchEmail(userName, password, subjectKeyword, fromEmail, bodySearchText);
}

public static void searchEmail(String userName, String password, final String subjectKeyword, final String fromEmail, final String bodySearchText) throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    boolean val = false;
    // server setting
    properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
    properties.put("mail.imap.host", "imap.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.imap.port", 143);

    // SSL setting
    properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", String.valueOf(143));
    properties.put("mail.imaps.ssl.checkserveridentity", "false");
    properties.put("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");
    properties.put("mail.imap.fetchsize", "519200");
    properties.put("mail.imaps.connectiontimeout", 1000);
    properties.put("mail.imaps.connectionpooltimeout", 1000);
    properties.put("mail.imaps.onTimeout", 1000);

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(
                            userName, password);// Specify the Username and the PassWord
                }
            });

    try {
        // connects to the message store
        Store store = session.getStore("imap");
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", Integer.parseInt("143"), userName, password);
        System.out.println("Connected to Email server….");
        // opens the inbox folder
        Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        folderInbox.close(false);
        store.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: try to change mail.imap.port to 587 https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/ or try https://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api-through-gmail-server

Comment: @Ganesh Gudghe

Tried 587 and got 

    javax.mail.MessagingException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
 at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:742)

Comment: you can try the second link javatpoint https://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api-through-gmail-server

Comment: @Ganesh Gudghe .   ok i see post with retrieve email bt its with pop3..so should i change from imap to pop3?